# how to view dowloaded file in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, download

i am downloading a pdf file from server,and i can see the file in my simulator.But i can't find in my device. I am saving the file into the document file. Below is my code,am sure my code is perfect,

```
 -(void)downloadPdfBtnPressed:(id)sender
{


    NSString *dowloadURL = [DownloadUrlArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag ]];
    NSString *filename =[dowloadURL lastPathComponent];

    NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/PDFDownload"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dowloadURL]];
    if(pdfData)
    {
        stringPath = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        [pdfData writeToFile:stringPath atomically:YES];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PDF"
                                                        message:@"PDF file is downloaded"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you explain what you your question is? What does your code do; what is wrong with the image size? You can used the [edit] button to add more explanation. That way you are more likely to get some help.

Comment: It would be best for you to link the library to iCarousel since this isn't something that is native to IOS: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Check the return value from `writeToFile` and use a version that returns an `NSError` object and upon failure, log the error description.

Comment: @trojanfoe return value show sdata,my problem is i couldnt see the downloaded file in my device

Comment: Have you turned on file sharing so you can see the file in iTunes?

Comment: @trojanfoe how to turn on file sharing?

Comment: Do a search on the internet.

Comment: @trojanfoe i had turned on UIFileSharingEnabled key to app’s Info.plist file, and set the value of the key to YES.still i cant c the file